# jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut not working in Internet Explorer 6, 7 or 8?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Hi Im using jQuery fade in/out on divs which contain images and text. It works fine in Firefox, Chrome and Safari however the effect doesn't appear to work at all in any Internet Explorer. The image disappears on fadeout the number of milliseconds I specified, but it doesn't fade.

Are there any special rules for using this in Explorer?

Comment: Are those div elements in a table by any chance?

Comment: I am having the same problem, but I don't even have a background image.  I'm just trying to fade in a simple red div with a user notification.  If I use .show() it works just fine, as does slideDown().  However, any fade at all, and IE appears to go into some sort of infinite loop - just sits forever hogging processor and "loading" the page.  Annoying, but I'm willing to just use .show() for now - working on deadline =o)  I can post some code though, if that will help anyone - it's only about 15 lines long.

Answer (score 0):

Does the element you are fading in and out have it's background color property set?

Answer (score 0):

I think more information is needed about the nature of the element itself, but my off-the-cuff guess is that something is wrong with your background-image (assuming you have one).

Post some code (CSS, HTML and JS), so we can really get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following HTML DIV which does not work using FadeIn/FadeOut in IE:

```
        <div class="tip"  style="width: 220px; display: none;">
            <div class="tip-header">
                <span><b>Title</b></span>
                <div class="right close"><a href="javascript:void(0);">close</a> <img alt=""  src="/Images/close-normal.png"/></div>
            </div>

            <div class="tip-content">EBody comes here.</div>
        </div> 


.tip
{
    display: block; 
    z-index: 99999; 
    position: fixed; 
    background-color: #ffffff; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); 
    border:solid 1px #82C2FA;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px; 
}

.tip-header
{
    padding: 8px; 
    min-height: 10px; 
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 8px; 
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius-topright: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius-topleft: 8px; 
     background-color: #CFE6FD; 
     border-bottom: 1px solid #82C2FA;  
}

.tip-header span
{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #666666;
}

.tip-content
{
    padding: 8px; 
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.close, .whats-this
{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.close a
{
    color: #085FBC; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

.close img
{
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: The background image is set well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is the ".tip" main div.

```
$(".tip").fadeIn("slow");
```

but this works in IE (weird):

```
$(".tip").show();
```